# Identify beginning and end of a run using Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a problem that I've managed to solve with iteration (shown), but I think there must be a way to query the database and get the same result?

```
short id;
if (someBoolean)
{
    id = 99;
    while (id > 0)
    {
        if (!db.MY_TABLEs.Any(x => x.ID == id))
            break;

        id--;
    }
}
else
{
    id = 1;
    while (id < 100)
    {
        if (!db.MY_TABLEs.Any(x => x.ID == id))
            break;

        id++;
    }                    
}
```

Basically I have a table full of integers that starts at 0 and ends at 100. There exists a gap in the data somewhere, could be 24-58 or 35-93, etc. Based on a `boolean` value I need to identify either the start of the gap, or the end of the gap.

**Sample Data**

```
{ 0, 1, 2, 98, 99, 100 }
// Start of gap, returns 3
// End of gap, returns 97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Range` and `Except` to get the desired result

```
//Input array { 0, 1, 2, 98, 99, 100 };
var array = db.MyTables.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

//Get the first and last elements
int a = array.OrderBy(x => x).First();
int b = array.OrderBy(x => x).Last();

//Fill the complete list
var completelist = Enumerable.Range(a, b - a + 1).ToList();

//Filter the missing list
var missingfromlist = completelist.Except(array).ToList();

//Read first and last element from missing list
Console.WriteLine($"Start of gap: { missingfromlist.First()}, End of gap : { missingfromlist.Last()}");
```

Output

```
Start of gap: 3, End of gap : 97
```